# Order in generic

Tags: ada

Suppose we have a types:

```
type ABC is (A, B, C);
type BAC is (B, A, C);
type CBA is (C, B, A);
```

Is there any way to declare generic package with parameter Order:

```
generic
   type Order is ...
package Pkg
    
   type Value_Type is ...
    
   type Value_Type_Array is array (Order) of Value_Type;
    
end Pkg;
```

that after instantiation I can have 3 different types:

```
AA : Package_ABC.Value_Type_Array;
BB : Package_BAC.Value_Type_Array;
CC : Package_CBA.Value_Type_Array;
```

Update: I forgot to say that I want use values of those types in the program. If we say that X, Y and Z are variables of type Value_Type:

```
begin
   AA (A) := X;
   AA (B) := Y;
   AA (C) := Z;
   ...
   BB (B) := X;
   BB (A) := Y;
   BB (C) := Z;
   ...
   CC (C) := X;
   CC (B) := Y;
   CC (A) := Z;
   ...
```

end;

Answer (score 5):

Enumeration types are discrete types (like integer types), so you would do:

```ada
generic
   type Order is (<>);
package Pkg
```

Comment: @JimLewis, No, this is Ada (like the question tag indicates), and while VHDL is based on Ada syntax, this was valid already in Ada 83

Comment: OOPs.   They sure do look similar.   Too bad not more similar and copied more into VHDL.  Sure would like to copy all the libraries.